# Clipping imagery to regions of interest with Google Earth Engine before exporting

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, landsat

My code currently collects all Landsat imagery and then creates a mean summer NDVI for each year.  I would like to clip the the summer raster to an vector polygon shapefile (such as attached).

[image]

Currently, I think my code just filters full Landsat rasters that have at least partial overlap with any polygon element in the ROI leaving me with huge, multigigabye rasters to export.  I only want the raster pixels within my ROI.

I would like to clip my combined Landsat 4-8 collections after line 120.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/620d62244bfe1cf910d7c38ddcd65187

edit:
Here is an asset for designating my ROI.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/edeutsch/ROI_2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clip` or `clipToCollection` to mask out pixels outside a geometry. You can then set `skipEmptyTiles` to True. To speed up the process, you could set each yearly image to one multiband image and export that one:

```
    // This will result in a single raster for each collection
var image = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(ee.List.sequence(Number(startYear), 
                                             Number(endYear)+1).map(function(year){
  var yearlyMean = mergedNDVI.filterDate(ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1,1), 
                                        ee.Date.fromYMD(ee.Number(year).add(1),1,1))
                                        .mean();
  return yearlyMean.rename(ee.String('NDVI').cat(ee.Number(year).format('%04d')))
}))
// to single image
  .toBands()
// clip to a featurecollection
  .clipToCollection(featureCollection)
print(image)

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: image,
    description: 'NDVI-Boreal_noLim-mean',
    scale: 30,
    region: studyRegion,
    maxPixels: 10000000000000,
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
    formatOptions: {
      cloudOptimized: true
    },
    skipEmptyTiles: true
  });
```

[Link to sample code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cf644cddceceeed120b82676674e1b71). Next time make sure your assets are shared so you code is reproducible.

Comment: thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I have a quick question.  In your code, on line 154, you have  "Number(endYear)+1)". Can you explain to me why it was the "+1"?  When I print the output in the console (Image), it says that it is for NDVI2020.  Is it trying to collection 2020 imagery or is it year ahead by one year and it is actually 2019's NDVI?